# webserver behind router or switch, multiple IPs available

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, router, switch, ufw

We are getting a new internet connection 100Mbps UP/DOWN and 4 Static IPs. Also on that connection there will be a webserver that hosts some websites for us. (Nothing too fancy).

The problem where we have in preparation to that connection is the wan setup. The idea we are considering is following:

```
Wan (ethernet) -> Switch -> Router/firewall -> internal network(300pcs)
                         -> Server (with UFW firewall)
```

And give the Router and the Server there own static IP.

Is this a good setup? Performance wise and security or do we need too put the server behind the Router.

What routers/switches do you recommend for this application?

Answer (score 0):

From security point of view, one firewall with 3 network interfaces will be enough for such a setup. You connect one interface to external network like Internet and connect another interface to the internal network, and connect the last one to the server(s) subnet which is called [DMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29).

This way you can allow traffic to pass from external to DMZ and does not allow it to pass from external to internal network. Publicly accessible servers should be placed in the DMZ.

As for the products recommendations, this part is off-topic!